# Pytorch, apply different transform to dataset after creation

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

Let's consider we create a dataset using `ImageFolder` class which we pass to it our data directory and an initial transform:

`init_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=path_to_data, transform=transforms.ToTensor())`

Then split it into **train** and **test**:

`train_data, test_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(init_dataset, [400, 116])`

What must we do if we want to apply a different **transform** to each of train and test data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way it could be done(thanks to this [pytorch discuss](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/changing-transformation-applied-to-data-during-training/15671)):

```
class MyDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, subset, transform=None):
        self.subset = subset
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x, y = self.subset[index]
        if self.transform:
            x = self.transform(x)
        return x, y
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.subset)
    

IMG_SIZE = 224  # Size of images used for training
IMG_MEAN = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
IMG_SDEV = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomRotation(30),
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(IMG_SIZE),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        transforms.Normalize(IMG_MEAN, IMG_SDEV)
    ]),

    'test': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(IMG_SIZE),
        transforms.Normalize(IMG_MEAN, IMG_SDEV)
    ])
}

train_data = MyDataset(train_data, transform=data_transforms['train'])
test_data = MyDataset(test_data, transform=data_transforms['test'])
```

Comment: Even when you're answering your own question, it should have some explanation as to what you're doing and how it solves the problem. The question lacks detail anyway